# How to set up Reverse Proxy for Shiny on AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, shiny, shiny-server

I have a Shiny server running on Amazon EC2 and I am routing all traffic from port 443 to 3838 via ELB and crated a domain entry in Route53. Now we have to set up authentication for the Shiny Apps since I am running a free version and not the pro it is not supported. 
Hence I was thinking of setting up a reverse proxy to force the users to authenticate themselves before viewing the reports.
Could you please help achieve it ?

Currently using Ubuntu 14.04 soon will upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks and regards,
Kunal Ghosh

Comment: look into `nginx` or `apache` and set it up

Comment: I recommend using [haproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) as a a reverse proxy. Its configuration is much simpler than nginx/apache/whatever. A quick search will reveal lots of config examples.